# Host process for windows services network activity between other computer on same network

Tags: network, windows, malware

Wondering if this is normal? I have two PCs hooked up to a router and when the other one powers up and I check my firewall I see that there's some sporadic network activity going on (mainly upload/download) between my computer and the other PC.

I also see activity when only my PC is powered on.

Could this be a malware? Both are running Windows 7.

Comment: It could be one of the mysterious communication done by MS Windows (a network neighborhood scan for instance). You could run wireshark on the other computer while booting and see what kind of packets you are getting (they will be probably encrypted, though, if this is Windows traffic)